# How do i create a listview in my video application?

Tags: java, android

Can someone tell me how should am i going to create my listview which look similar [here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/comment-page-3/#comments).

Problem 1: The listview example i show in the link only caters to 2 file object as you can see in the link but in my own context i need a rather more "dynamic" video_list which increase/decrease with respect to time, 
but how am i going to fulfill the sort of look and feel in my codes which has icons, file name, and file size yet at the same time looking clean and simple on each file object??

Problem 2: And why is my listview having error when the directory is empty despite having this to handle the "empty" in my xml

```
<TextView
  android:id="@id/android:empty"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:text="No File Directory found on SD Card"/>
```

Can someone guide on this matter because i'm rather new in android/java... Thanks

This is what i tried out so far...

```
public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> videoItems = null;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.videolistview);

         getVideoFiles(new File("/sdcard/Video_List").listFiles());
     }

     public void getVideoFiles(File[] videoList) 
     {
         videoItems = new ArrayList<String>();

          for (File file : videoList) 
          {
            videoItems.add(file.getName());
          }

          setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, videoItems));  
     }

     @Override
     protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
     {

     }
}
```

EDITED

Comment: Did you check the android dev guide? http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Comment: Post some code for which you're having a problem and we'll gladly help or try eLance to get your code written for you.

Comment: @Bill Mote Hi i have added more details of wht i want but really i quite bad in programming could you lend me a hand which i need it desperately... :(

Comment: @Aleadam I have read the link you offered but its offering mere "hard-coding" rather than some sort of dynamic coding as seen because video increase/decrease in a directory.... Could you help in this matter? Could you read ahove becos i have added more details..

Answer (score 0):

To add your list of videos, simply use the following line:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Videos));
```

Comment: But if i wanted the look and feel of what was seen here http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/comment-page-3/#comments but my above codes don't seems to be suitable to be integrated together? Or rather how should i use the link instead to display the string for my video directory?

Comment: @misery you will have to implement an adapter similar to `OrderAdapter` in that link.

Comment: I have did some modification to my codes above can you please take a look, see how can i implement the above into my codes?